# How can I stop 'Obtaining <filename>'?

Tags: netrw

I am new to vim, and I use netrw as a file explorer.

Frequently hit shift-P to open a file in a buffer.  Sometimes I accidentally hit [shift-O](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-O), and netrw will start obtaining the file.  How do I cancel cancel that?

Two changes I see happen are a new split opens with the below message

> **warning** (netrw) cannot determine method (format: protocol://[user@]hostname[:port]/[path])

Which I can close.
But also I see a message in the status/message bar.  What I really want to do is get rid of that message: **Obtaining index.html**

[image]

The above documentation, suggests that the message will end when the transfer completes.  So maybe I need to cancel the transfer.  I scanned/searched the above documentation for the words cancel and transfer and found nothing to suggest a fix.

Comment: What about `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: That does not seem to help.  I can tell you when I hit shift-O, I get a new split with the message: "**warning** (netrw) cannot determine method (format: protocol://[user@]hostname[:port]/[path])".

Comment: You can try to put `let g:netrw_silent= 1` in your .vimrc (you can find it [here](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#g%3Anetrw_silent)). I hope it will help.

Comment: sorry, no dice :(

Comment: Chipping away at this, it is being set in status line: `set statusline?` to see how it modified it.

Comment: I guess I could write a function? that intercepts shift-O, stores statusline, executes shift-O, and if g:netrw_silent==1, reset statusline...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call

```
:set statusline&
```

Comment: It [resets statusline to the default value](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:set-default).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using netrw v155d; I don't see the split taking place (just the error message, which a :q handles just fine).  Perhaps you should try updating your netrw: http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW

Comment: Are you sure you don't have [use errorwindow](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#g%3Anetrw_use_errorwindow) set?  I am pretty sure I found my answer.

Comment: Thankyou @TMB, g:netrw_use_errorwindow was the setting I was looking for, that error window has been driving me nuts!